# What is happening today with new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

The amount of unsalvable questions of new users is very high today. Did Stackoverflow launch a new ad campaign for more users or something?

Some examples:

1. [Session in Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821425/session-in-code-igniter)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821434/session-related-error
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818281/how-to-take-backup-of-mysql-database-automatically-everyday

Is there an explanation for this or am I the only one who notices this?

Comment: How have you determined today is so much higher than normal? Perhaps you are just noticing it more today for some reason?

Comment: I think this will always progressively get worse. Burden of being popular on the internet. Good reason for community moderation. All we can do is keep on educating.

Comment: Three bad questions is your threshold for "very high unsalvable questions"? Honestly, I don't think it's getting worse at a faster rate than usual. I'm with Matt. It's ALWAYS getting worse, but on what looks like a linear progression, so... *shrugs* to be expected, I guess?

Comment: @Patrice I counted a least 10 in the past 2 hours. But it could just be me

Comment: @AgeDeO 10 in the past 2 hours? again, that's... normal (sad, but normal)

Comment: Why don't you ask those new users?

Comment: Ugh, [tag:php], no wonder! I kid, I kid...

Comment: All 3 questions are tagged with PHP, what else do you expect ?

Comment: This is an observational study. Stand by the side of the road and execute the assignment: count all green cars in an hour. After an hour you'll be able to give a pretty accurate count of green cars. Then give the answer to the question: and how many red cars? You don't know, because you weren't paying attention to that; that's the reason why observational studies are useless, they only show what you want to see, and ignore everything else. Case in point: this one is done by looking at questions that actually make it to the site, probably in a particular tag.

Comment: @Gimby: Have you read The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-time? I highly recommend it. The fifteenth chapter in particular, Chapter 47, has an incredibly eye-opening perspective on observing cars.

Comment: @BoltClock no and you have just made my day, I'm ordering it right away.

Comment: Maybe the hub-hub about 10 million questions obscured it a bit, but we blew right past the 10,000 questions per day threshold.  That's one question every ~6 seconds during the busy hours.  Yikes.  Well, they are not all keepers.

Comment: It seems that sometimes a certain type of bad question will suddenly be popular. Some days it seems like all anyone wants to ask are recommendation questions, on other days it's troubleshooting questions that are only 2 sentences long and no code. I'm willing to bet there are spikes related to certain points on the calendar, academic, and fiscal year but I could only guess if any of those apply today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there an explanation for this

1. It's PHP.
2. It's Monday.

But in all seriousness, I don't know. Once I saw a bunch of bad questions about a same, very specific topic, that *didn't* sound like homework, all crop up on the same day. But it was a Sunday<sup>1</sup>, and none of those questions were about PHP. So I have no explanation for that incident, and I'm not sure there is a plausible explanation for this either.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I don't even remember if it was.</sub>

Comment: https://twitter.com/PHP_CEO/status/647915833818251264

Comment: @Pekka 웃: TARTAN IS GREAT, THOUGH.

Comment: PHP CEO is just epic. https://twitter.com/PHP_CEO/status/549719518420152321